# Rails :allow_destroy => true in Active Record Nested Attributes works in development but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, nested-attributes

I am using nested form in my rails app and setup as below:

Models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

Controllers:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def edit     
    if @post.location.blank?
     @post.build_location
    end
  end

  def update    
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post was upated."
      redirect_to edit_category_post_path(@category, @post)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "There was an error saving a post, please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, location_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :zipcode, :state, :_destroy])
  end

end
```

Views:

app/views/locations/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %> 
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Delete." %> 
  </br>

  <%= f.label :street %> (optional)
  <%= f.text_field :street, class: 'form-control',placeholder: "123 A Street" %>
</div>
```

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="well">
  <%= f.fields_for :location do |location| %>
    <%= render 'locations/form', f: location %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Everything worked as expected in development mode. In development, when I tested the edit function, I clicked the destroy check-box in the location form, the location object was deleted and location_id became `nil`. However, after pushing to Heroku, I found that the `:allow_destroy => true` option in NestedAttributes didn't work and created below error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "locations" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_ccec1da3aa" on table "posts"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "posts".
```

In the console, the location_id still connected to the post object. I have tried to delete the object in console but it still showed the same error. For some reasons, once the location object was created with the post, I could not delete the location object with the destroy check box in the production mode.

I have been researching all the possible solutions in the past two days, but so far I still haven't figured out the solution yet.

**Note:**
In my case, I want to keep the `post` when I delete the `location` object.

Comment: Your local db most likely does not reflect what's in your migration. Try creating a new db on your local and run your migrations. That should reproduce the error.

Comment: @dan-klasson: I have recreated the db on my local, but it didn't reproduce the error in development, only in production.

Answer (score 0):

Deletion of `location` fails because you are likely to have *another* `post` referencing that `location` (`Class Post ... belongs_to: location`).

You need to delete all posts that reference your `location`, and then it will be possible to delete `location`.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I don't want to delete all posts associated location object, though; it is an option for user to delete `location` in their posts.

Comment: @FlorenceLiang You need to rethink your relations between posts and locations. Or, in case you don't want to delete location itself but just make particular post to have no location, set `location` of `post` to `null` instead of deleting `location`.